# How can I make Compare-Object detect swapped lines

Tags: powershell

I compare the below shown files using Compare-Object. But despite having swapped lines, the script outputs *Files are the same*. How can I compare two files such that swapped lines are detected as differences?

```
$fileA = "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\fileA.txt"
$fileB = "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\fileB.txt"


if(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content $fileA) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content $fileB))
    {"files are different"} 
Else 
    {"Files are the same"}
```

fileA.txt

```
A
B
C
```

fileB.txt

```
A
C
B
```

Comment: what kind of difference are you wanting to detect? if just "different", then take a look at `Get-Help Get-FileHash`. [*grin*]

Comment: Yes, I only need to classify if the files are 'same' or 'differen'. So yes your solution works fine. Based on the grin, do you think this is a good solution or more a hack?

Comment: You might just compare the whole file as a string using the `-Raw` switch: `Get-Content -Raw $fileA`

Comment: @rot8 - the idea of "is it differnt in any way?" is what file hashes are designed for. so i recommend using it. ///// the [*grin*] is my indication of feeling like smiling.

Comment: While comparing file hashes will be more efficient, you can use parameter `-SyncWindow 0` to prevent Compare-Object from matching elements in any position: `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content $fileA) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content $fileB) -SyncWindow 0`